# setInterval in prototype, RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js

Something is wrong in my code. I'm trying to start interval calling Prototype function in object contructor on new Tournament(). But node.js throwing an error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

When I'm not assinging timer to Tournament object, everything is fine.
var timer = setInterval(); works good as well.

Could you please explain me?

```
var Tournament = function() {
    var tournament = this;
    console.log("Creating new instance.");
    this.users = [];
    this.state = 'waitingForPlayers';
    this._id = generateId();
    this.startTimer(6, tournament.startTournament);
};

Tournament.prototype.startTimer = function(time, timoutCallback) {
    var tournament = this;
    tournament.time = time; 
    tournament.timer = setInterval(function() {
        tournament.time--;
        console.log(Tournament.time);
        if(tournament.time <= 0) {
            clearInterval(tournament.timer);
            timoutCallback();
        };
    }, 1000);
};

Tournament.prototype.startTournament = function() {
    console.log("Tournament is starting.");
};


Edited:
I'm creating instance:

var tournament = new Tournament();
game.instances.push(tournament);
```

Comment: What is going on with your `var Tournament = this;` notation? At best, you're confusing classes and instances. Anyway, nothing you've shown actually executes anything. Is the problem kicked off by trying to instantiate a `Tournament`? What is `Tournament.startTournament`, and are you sure that should not be `this.startTournament.bind(this)`?

Comment: Yes, when Im trying to create instance, node.js is throwing an error. When I'm not assinging setInterval reference to any variable, everything is working cool. But I need to assing to have possibility of stopping this interval. Well callbackTimeout works good too.

Comment: You need to show us `startTournament`. Or is that a typo for `startTimer`?

Comment: Prototype of Tournament, I'v edited

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with this code (except that it should be `console.log(tournament.time)`). Works fine in the browser.

Comment: Yeah I'v probably got an error in other place. But thats werid, that when I'm not using reference for interval, it works good. Mby node.js bug?

Comment: What do you mean by "using reference for interval"?

Comment: tournament.timer = setInterval(...)

Comment: Ok I know the problem. I was emiting this instance by socket insteed of emiting only of instance.data. socket.emit('updateGameData', { instance: instance }); Probably that didn't like reference of working interval. Thanx for help. Some errors in node.js are very unclean ;/

Comment: I don't think the errors are due to node not being clean, it's more that you're not referencing the correct timer reference, closures can be a bitch.